# Unwanted connections to Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, debian, phantomjs

I've just put online an LAMP (for our content) and a Tomcat server with PhantomJS (for creating Highcharts) on a Debian 8 (Jessie).

I get some unwanted connections mainly on port 8443 (but also on 8009 as shown below) :

```
tcp6     184      0 <Our server>:8443 80.245.19.133:52632     CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp6      90      0 <Our server>:8443 sh2150.evanzo-ser:53958 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp6      90      0 <Our server>:8443 sh2150.evanzo-ser:56898 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp6       0      0 <Our server>:8009 s2.securityresear:60000 ESTABLISHED
```

I have about 40 "CLOSE_WAIT" connections permanently from various host like "sh2150.evanzo-ser..." and "s2.securityresear...".

What can I do to prevent this ?

Comment: It depends on what you call unwanted connections. Do you have a fixed list of "authorized" connection IPs ?

Comment: No I don't have an authorized fixed list of allowed IPs. However the Tomcat server is only for creating charts (highcharts) with PhantomJS inside our intranet (that's ruined on a LAMP).

Comment: Does the Tomcat server have separate IPs for internet and intranet access?

Comment: No the Tomcat server has the same IP as the Apache server but obviously a different port (8443)

Answer (score 0):

CLOSE_WAIT connections go away after a while. CLOSE_WAIT indicates that the remote endpoint (other side of the connection) has closed the connection. TIME_WAIT indicates that local endpoint (this side) has closed the connection. The connection is being kept around so that any delayed packets can be matched to the connection and handled appropriately. The connections will be removed when they time out within four minutes [says superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/173535/what-are-close-wait-and-time-wait-states).

The only case where you should be worried is if those never go away (ie. getting more and more). That's an [indication your code is never closing the connection](http://blogs.technet.com/b/janelewis/archive/2010/03/09/explaining-close-wait.aspx) after sending a response.

However, you should not be overly worried by random connections. If you have **any** service exposed to the internet, there will be botnets spraying requests all over it within minutes, looking for exploitable holes. There are rules lists you can use to mitigate this traffic, eg. by [spamhaus](https://www.spamhaus.org/bcl/). Just realized this causes maintenance on your side and can lead to IPs getting blocked for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That clarifies the situation. however what about "ESTABLISHED", like this one :

 "tcp6       0      0 <Our server>:8009 s2.securityresear:60000 ESTABLISHED"

Comment: That's most likely a bot that tries to attach to the AJP port. You should block it to outside traffic in the firewall: http://diablohorn.com/2011/10/19/8009-the-forgotten-tomcat-port/